# Location of GlassFish Server Logs

Tags: logging, netbeans, glassfish

I have NetBeans IDE installed on a Windows 7 64-bit machine.  Obviously, NetBeans comes with the GlassFish server.

I am currently having problems with a project and would like to check the server logs.  Where are these stored please?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In general the logs are in `/YOUR_GLASSFISH_INSTALL/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/`.

In NetBeans go to the "Services" tab open "Servers", right-click on your Glassfish instance and click "View Domain Server Log".

If this doesn't work right-click on the Glassfish instance and click "Properties", you can see the folder with the domains under "Domains folder". Go to this folder -> your-domain -> logs

If the server is already running you should see an `Output` tab in NetBeans which is named similar to `GlassFish Server x.x.x`

You can also use `cat` or `tail -F` on `/YOUR_GLASSFISH_INSTALL/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log`. If you are using a different domain then `domain1` you have to adjust the path for that.

Comment: I've found that for the current version (8.1) you need to go into the "output" pane and inside the "GlassFish Server 4.1.1" tab to find your stack trace.

Answer (score 25):

Locate the installation path of GlassFish. Then move to `domains/domain-dir/logs/`
and you'll find there the log files. If you have created the domain with NetBeans, the domain-dir is most probably called `domain1`.

See this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/abluk.html) for the official GlassFish documentation about logging.

Comment: I use NetBeans 8.2: in the GlassFish Server properties there are two paths: the **Installation path** and the **Domain Folder**. They have similar structure, but in my case, the log file was in the **Domain Folder** (_C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\config\GF_4.1\domain1\logs_)

Answer (score 23):

```
tail -f /path/to/glassfish/domains/YOURDOMAIN/logs/server.log
```

You can also upload log from admin console : `http://yoururl:4848`

[image]

Comment: I like it.  can you get the same result, a zip file of logs, from ssh?

Comment: yep! ==> `scp usernameofserver@ipserver:/path/to/glassfish/domains/YOURDOMAIN/logs/server.log .;zip server.log.zip server.log`