# See the console in a java web in netbeans

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

How I can see the console to see my:

```
System.out.println ("param1 =" + input.param1);)
```

In a java web project in netbeans?

I thought maybe I should see it in the admin console of my glassfish server, but when I try to enter the browser opens and asks me a username and password. 
Look in netbeans, services, servers, glassfish, properties and look at my user (admin) and password, and I write and tell me wrong. 
I have also tried admin / adminadmin, does not work. 
Any idea?

Thanks:

Comment: this should be printed in the server logs

Comment: where is the server log ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835913/location-of-glassfish-server-logs

Comment: thank you very much,but this not working for my...

Comment: typo or error : `System.out.println ("param1 =" + input.param1);)` a brace too much `);)`

Comment: can you make a screenshot of netbeans while running your java prg.

Comment: I've already solved. Reinstall netbeans and Glasfish. Now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To see the output in a console, you would need to look in GLASSFISH SERVER window pane. (This is where you would see both your server logs and other output)

..... To get to the GLASSFISH SERVER window

- Click on WINDOW
- Click on OUTPUT
- When you run your web app, go to OUTPUT(this should be besides your other window pane)
- Click on GLASSFISH SERVER window and scroll down to the last output(you should see your outputs)