# very Strange Glassfish deploy is failing

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, ubuntu-14.04, glassfish-4

I'm working under Ubuntu, for Java EE I use Eclipse and GlassFish.  I'm experiencing a strange problem.

Everything is just fine, except when I want import aglib for jstl library. Whenever I write these lines in web.xml:

```
<jsp-config>
<jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/includes/taglibs.jsp</include-prelude>
</jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

I have this problem:

> Publishing to GlassFish 4 at localhost[domain1] ... has encountered a
>   problem cannot deploy 'apps name'
>
> Cannot deploy 'apps name' deploy is failing=Application with name
>   ['apps name'] is not deployed

Any help would be appreciated - I really hate to write the taglib line for every jsp page.

Comment: What does the glassfish console say?

Comment: hi this is a screenshoot of the console http://postimg.org/image/o1q5nmlmh/

Comment: That's the admin console. I was talking about the console to which glassfish outputs its logging. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25361818/2828908) answer for instructions on how to open the log. Please update your question with the relevant bit of the log after a failed deployment.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that deleting the Glassfish server from eclipse and adding a new one resolves the Cannot deploy 'apps name' deploy is failing=Application with name ['apps name'] is not deployed error at times.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was not necessary to delete the Glassfish server to fix it. Directly refactor the project name (right click at the project node on `package explorer-->refactor-->rename`). Then you can compile the project without that exception again.