# GlassFish Http Status 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp, glassfish, crud

When I try to run my Web Application (a basic CRUD) using JSP, the GlassFish server returns the follow message:

HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

**type** Exception report

**message** Internal Server Error

**description** The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**

java.lang.NullPointerException

**note** The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.

And I don't knhow what to do. I think the error is in connection with my DB. I'm using PostgreSQL, running in a Windows.

My NetBeans project is in GitHub [Crisfa Project](https://github.com/rflpazini/Crisfa)

Comment: [NullPointerException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An HTTP 500 error is meaningless. It is only telling you that something went wrong, although you can see that whatever it was was down to a null pointer error. You need to look in the server logs to see what caused the null pointer error.

This StackOverflow question has a few good answers on how to find the server logs, either manually through the file system, or with NetBeans. [Location of GlassFish Server Logs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13835913/212224)