# Database connection in Java Servlet

Tags: java, mysql, database, servlets, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to a database in a Java Servlet, but I am unable to connect. I searched on google and each website is showing different way I don't know why.

Here is the code that I tried to connect, but nothing(data) is going to MySQL database rows.

```
public class DBConnection{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final Connection connection;
    private final String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Servlet";
    private final String user = "root";
    private final String pwd = "";
    public DBConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pwd);
    }

    public Connection gC(){
        return this.connection;
    }
}
```

Here is I'm trying to insert data in database (but data is not adding to DB).

```
public class ReServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try{
            String uName=req.getParameter("uName");
            String uEmail=req.getParameter("uEmail");
            String uPass=req.getParameter("uPass");
            DBConnection conn=new DBConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps;
            ps = conn.gC().prepareStatement("insert into users(name,email,password) values (?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, uName);
            ps.setString(2, uEmail);
            ps.setString(3, uPass);
            ps.execute();
        }catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException se){
           se.printStackTrace();

        }finally{
        } 
    }
}
```

I also request to all, please give me simple and easy database connection example, about each website is showing with full registration or any other system. But I just want simple db connection example as I am trying in my code.

**Edited**
By replacing `se.printStackTrace();` to this `throw new RuntimeException(se);` I'm getting this Exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: Why `DBConection` extends `HTTPServlet`? You get any exceptions?

Comment: @Jens Sorry, I was trying different way, and forget to remove that. Where I can see exception? there is nothing during compile time.

Comment: You can see it in the logfiles of your server

Comment: @Jens Sorry I'm new to Servlet, I'm using netbeans and GlassFish, where I can see? In which folder?

Comment: For debugging only, you might want to consider replacing `se.printStackTrace()` with `throw new RuntimeException(se)` so the exception is displayed in the browser. Most likely reason btw is the fact your password is empty.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel there is no password, I'm using default password.

Comment: i am not working with netbeans and glassfish so i can not say where the logs are. Maybe it is in the console or you can ask google.

Comment: @Jens by using Mark method, I got this Exception. `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` now what to do?

Comment: You should also check if mysql is running and the database must exists

Comment: For logs (you will need them): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835913/location-of-glassfish-server-logs

Comment: You may set `Connection.setAutocommit(true)` to get out of doubts.

Comment: @PeterMmm where to add? I'm getting this Exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Answer (score -1):

You nedd to register your driver with DriverManager like this:

```
   Class c = Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   DriverManager.registerDriver( c.newInstance() );
```

Please remember to close your connection in finally block.

Comment: I think it could solve my Problem but where to add these lines?

Comment: In your DBConnection constructor.