# Why does glassfish not show the full stacktrace?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Glassfish is not showing the full stacktrace with class name, line number etc. it only comes up with:

```
[2015-10-27T19:47:08.312+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [org.glassfish.enterprise.concurrent] [tid: _ThreadID=362 _ThreadName=concurrent/__defaultManagedThreadFactory-Thread-13] [timeMillis: 1445971628312] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  java.lang.NullPointerException]]
```

That's it. Where does the NPE comes from?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835913/location-of-glassfish-server-logs

Comment: Unfortunately nobody can answer where an exception comes from when there is 0 information available as that really is a crystal ball question. At this point you'd need to be a lot more forthcoming about your setup. Are there more logs? Are you deploying applications or is this just a vanilla clean server boot? Did you try cleaning the generated folder? Did you make any recent changes to configuration files. etc. etc.

Comment: HI, sorry but i dont know what you mean. i cleaned everything, there are no more logs, only the nullpointer and then the programm stops. I knoww its stupid, but i dont know which informations are necassary to find the problem. The .war will be deployed sucessfully, i run the programm and it works until it came to the specific point whjere the nullpointer came up. So on configuration i did not make any changes. could this be because i dont inject object by cdi, instead i am using "new"

Comment: at the admin console look at server-config -> logger settings -> log levels and make sure everything is set to INFO or higher (no OFF)

Comment: thank you, but everything is on INFO

Comment: I use this catch for example:              catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Logger.getLogger(MyReader.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, null, ex);

But also the ex.print dont show the whole stacktrace :(

Comment: Does anything change when you don't pass null for the log message? I'm just grasping at straws here.

Comment: No it dont change anything. Caould it be because the container dont know the object? But this will be stupid!